# Looping Datasource Entity Framework Database First using Postgresql

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, postgresql, datasource

i am newbie.
i am using EF 6.0 with Postgresql (Npgsql v 2.2.5.0)

BRIEF DESCRIPTION:

i have 3 tables:

- supplier table (ms_supplier) for storing info about suppliers
- vendor invoice (nota_supplier) for storing info about invoices
- supplier bank account numbers (no_rekening_bank) for storing info about vendor bank accounts info

Database created on Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE ms_supplier
(
  ms_supplier_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ms_supplier_id_seq'::regclass),
  kode_supplier text NOT NULL,
  nama_supplier text NOT NULL,
  alamat text NOT NULL,
  tempo integer,
  keterangan_tambahan text,
  CONSTRAINT ms_supplier_id PRIMARY KEY (ms_supplier_id)
)

CREATE TABLE nota_supplier
(
  nota_supplier_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  tanggal_nota date NOT NULL,
  nominal numeric NOT NULL,
  ms_supplier_id bigint NOT NULL,
  status_pembayaran boolean NOT NULL,
  keterangan text,
  tanggal_jatuh_tempo date NOT NULL,
  tanggal_barang_datang date NOT NULL,
  nomer_nota text NOT NULL,
  tanggal_input date,
  diinput_oleh text,
  CONSTRAINT nota_supplier_id PRIMARY KEY (nota_supplier_id),
  CONSTRAINT ms_supplier_id FOREIGN KEY (ms_supplier_id)
      REFERENCES ms_supplier (ms_supplier_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE rekening_bank_supplier
(
  rekening_bank_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  nama_bank text NOT NULL,
  nomer_rekening text NOT NULL,
  nama_pemilik_rekening text NOT NULL,
  ms_supplier_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT rekening_bank_id PRIMARY KEY (rekening_bank_id),
  CONSTRAINT ms_supplier_id FOREIGN KEY (ms_supplier_id)
      REFERENCES ms_supplier (ms_supplier_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

UPDATED: *removed edmc picture because link limitation*

Class generated from database first:

```
    public partial class ms_supplier
        {
            public ms_supplier()
            {
                this.ms_barang = new HashSet<ms_barang>();
                this.telpon_supplier = new HashSet<telpon_supplier>();
                this.rekening_bank_supplier = new HashSet<rekening_bank_supplier>();
                this.nota_supplier = new HashSet<nota_supplier>();
            }

            public long ms_supplier_id { get; set; }
            public string kode_supplier { get; set; }
            public string nama_supplier { get; set; }
            public string alamat { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> tempo { get; set; }
            public string keterangan_tambahan { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ms_barang> ms_barang { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<telpon_supplier> telpon_supplier { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<rekening_bank_supplier> rekening_bank_supplier { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<nota_supplier> nota_supplier { get; set; }
        }
    }


     public partial class nota_supplier
        {
            public long nota_supplier_id { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime tanggal_nota { get; set; }
            public decimal nominal { get; set; }
            public long ms_supplier_id { get; set; }
            public bool status_pembayaran { get; set; }
            public string keterangan { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime tanggal_jatuh_tempo { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime tanggal_barang_datang { get; set; }
            public string nomer_nota { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> tanggal_input { get; set; }
            public string diinput_oleh { get; set; }

            public virtual ms_supplier ms_supplier { get; set; }
        }

public partial class rekening_bank_supplier
    {
        public long rekening_bank_id { get; set; }
        public string nama_bank { get; set; }
        public string nomer_rekening { get; set; }
        public string nama_pemilik_rekening { get; set; }
        public long ms_supplier_id { get; set; }

        public virtual ms_supplier ms_supplier { get; set; }
    }

public partial class telpon_supplier
{
    public long telpon_id { get; set; }
    public string jenis_telpon { get; set; }
    public string nomer_telpon { get; set; }
    public long ms_supplier_id { get; set; }

    public virtual ms_supplier ms_supplier { get; set; }
}
public partial class HMERPEntities : DbContext
    {
        public HMERPEntities()
            : base("name=HMERPEntities")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<kategori_barang> kategori_barang { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<kategori_kontak> kategori_kontak { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ms_barang> ms_barang { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ms_user> ms_user { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<penggolongan_warna> penggolongan_warna { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<satuan> satuans { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<warna> warnas { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ms_setoran_toko> ms_setoran_toko { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ms_supplier> ms_supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<telpon_supplier> telpon_supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<rekening_bank_supplier> rekening_bank_supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<nota_supplier> nota_supplier { get; set; }
    }
```

and then when adding datasource, it looks loopy:
[loopy datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehIbY.png)

GOAL: able to load ms_supplier table and related entity (master detail view) using eager loading on a windows form

PROBLEM:
when using query like this:

```
using (var context = new HMERPEntities())
            {
                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var query = context.ms_supplier.Include("nota_supplier").ToList();
                ms_supplierBindingSource.DataSource = query;
}
```

my ms_supplier table loaded fine, on the query result i can see some data about nota_supplier table, but my nota_supplierDataGridView seems like not binding correctly with the master.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIeMm.png)

DOUBTS:

1. is my loopy datasource shown in picture 1 will cause any problem?
2. is the default type hash set on my ms_supplier class causing the related entity not being shown on notaSupplierDataGridView? is yes, what will be the correct type for loading nota_supplier table?

   ```
           this.nota_supplier = new HashSet<nota_supplier>();
   ```

best regards,
Handoko

Comment: What is the problem? Since you have one-to-one relationship you automatically get links between the objects and can go back and forth. Is it causing issues?

Comment: Hello Sami, thanks for your reply. I did not know that the reported behaviour is a normal one. My problem is: my gridview for nota_supplier is empty while the ms_supplier works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i fix this problem by changing my code from:

```
            public virtual <ms_barang> ms_barang { get; set; }
            public virtual <telpon_supplier> telpon_supplier { get; set; }
            public virtual <rekening_bank_supplier> rekening_bank_supplier { get; set; }
            public virtual <nota_supplier> nota_supplier { get; set;}
```

to:

```
        public virtual ICollection<ms_barang> ms_barang { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<telpon_supplier> telpon_supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<rekening_bank_supplier> rekening_bank_supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<nota_supplier> nota_supplier { get; set; }
```